# File upload in laravel 4.2, malicious file uploaded!! ( File Type checks and file Type extension checks not working)

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I have an app which allows users to upload images files in `.jpg .png .jpeg` format. A user uploaded a `jpg.php` file, after speaking with him, he informed me he edited the image to include PHP code after the image content and then accessed the image to run the code, My folder permissions were 755 and the file permissions were 644, user and group were www:data. The app is written in the laravel 4.2 framework.

Can I add anything to this code to prevent this happening again? I'm not a pro coder and don't claim to be.

```
public function doCreateListing(){
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    $rules = array(
        'title'     =>'required',
        'description'   =>'required',
        'tags'          => 'required',
        'category'      => 'required',
        'price'         => 'required|numeric|min:0',
        'image_1' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
        'image_2' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
        'image_3' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
        'image_4' => 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
    );


//save image
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/uploads/';
        $j=1;
        for ($i=1; $i <=4 ; $i++) {
            if (Input::hasFile('image_'.$i)){
                $primary_image=0;
                if($j==1) $primary_image=1; //For default, the first image is the primary image. 

                $file = Input::file('image_'.$i);

                $filename_ = str_random(8);
                $filename = str_replace(" ", "-", $file->getClientOriginalName());
                $file_uploaded=$filename_.'_'.$filename;
                $upload_success  = $file->move($destinationPath, $file_uploaded); 
                if( $upload_success ) {
                    $listing_image = new ListingImage();
                    $listing_image->listing_id = $listing->id;
                    $listing_image->image =  $file_uploaded;
                    $listing_image->primary_image =  $primary_image; 
                    $listing_image->save();                                            
                }
                $j++;  
            }
        }           
    }
    return Redirect::to('listings')->with('success','Your image was set.');
}
```

Comment: where in your code did you use the `$rules`?

Comment: read these: https://medium.com/@igordata/php-running-jpg-as-php-or-how-to-prevent-execution-of-user-uploaded-files-6ff021897389, https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/20390 (although this is for Laravel 5.4). You might want to consider upgrading to a higher version of Laravel, but I understand that there will be many breaking changes once you do that.